# How to install redhat linux on HP DL380 G6 server

Tags: linux, redhat, hp-proliant

I have here DL380 G6 server, But i have not been able to install the redhat linux on it.

Its smart start disk do not have linux on it.
When i directly boot from DVD it boots in GUI mode but when selects automatic partition it gives an error and after clicking ok it Reboots.

the error relates to disk.

Please advice

Comment: What version of Red Hat Enterprise are you using? When you say "Red Hat Linux" that is an ancient product lineup that ended at version 9. Even early versions of Enterprise do not understand modern disk controllers and will fail to partition the disk(s). This is the most likely cause of your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The G6 servers should be covered with recent CCISS driver updates from RedHat. Are you installing from the original CDs or have you downloaded ISOs from later updates? If you're using the original CDs or an old update, you'll need a driver disk.

Here's the link to the [driver disk needed for RHEL 5 64-bit on a ProLiant DL380 G6](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&prodNameId=3884083&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-556ec9e4e8a94034baec7f20a2).

Here is the [general listing for the DL380 G6](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3884083&taskId=135&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&lang=en&cc=us).

Select the OS of your choice and then the driver disk link. Follow those installation instructions and work from there.

Comment: And here's HP's list of certified Linux distributions: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/hplinuxcert.html

Answer (score 4):

HP chose not to certify the G6 line for RHEL 7.  Also, the CCISS and some other drivers were deprecated and [not included in RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/Known-Issues-Kernel.html) due to lack of vendors' desire to support/certify that older hardware.

See [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/874443) for details on the switch from CCISS driver to HPSA driver, or use the HP provided CCISS driver.

Comment: The P410 controller used in the DL380 G6 doesn't need any special help or additional steps for EL7. The G7 platform shares the same driver set. The link that you posted is for G5 systems and previous generation P400 controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Any errors?  Did this system have an OS on it before or it is a new disk?

I've seen an issue where the installer will fail due to pre-existing partitions and boot data.

You can boot into rescue mode and then blow out the partition data on the disk:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024 count=100

The above command will zero out the first 100KB of the disk.

Comment: at what point should i type this command

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error does it give?  This sounds like it doesn't see a disk (array) at all and therefore you need to find the correct driver to use during the installation procedure.

To use the driver disk you would enter "linux dd" at the first prompt of the install.